# Lifting or lifted

Tags: grammar

Which sentence is correct?  Please help.

> John stood there with his head **lifted**.
>   John stood there  with  his
>   head **lifting**.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Both are correct. Please [edit] to say if you mean "His head was motionless and held up while he stood" or "He moved his head up while he stood"

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you want to say "lifted."

Lifting one's head is a process that typically takes less than a second; it would be highly unusual to describe someone as standing there with his head lifting.